# How to filter messages in Firefox Error Console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, trace, error-console

Some of the web pages that I need to be open, while developing my script, produce a lot of errors that go into the Error Console of the Firefox. This makes it really hard to spot the errors, which are produced by the script, that I am trying to develop. Is there any way to filter the errors in Error Console? For example display only those that begin with my custom tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a console prividing some filter and search capabilities like [Console²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/). It replaces the standard console with a more powerful version and works quite well. And it has a search box.

Comment: Not compatible with newer versions of Firefox at the timing of writing this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nowadays you can filter in the console, using built-in functionality. You can select different type of console messages, or even filter by a custom string, such as your own tag.

Comment: The search feature even now supports [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Filtering_with_Regular_Expressions) like `/(script1[.]js|script2[.]js)/` to only show output relating to certain files.

Answer (score 0):

Have checked console.group method? This should be excatly what you are looking for

<s>http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.log.28object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29</s> 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group